# What items grant bonuses to Heal skill checks?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, dnd-3e, equipment

In Wizards of the Coast's *Dungeons and Dragons, 3rd Edition* and *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5* corpus, the number of items I've found that grant a direct bonus to [Heal](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/skills/heal.htm) skill checks is 2.

- The [**healer's kit**](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/equipment/goodsAndServices.htm#healersKit) (*PH* 128, 130) (50 gp; 1 lb.) grants a +2 circumstance bonus to Heal skill checks. *Note:* As the perfect tool for the skill Heal, it doesn’t stack with a masterwork tool (*PH* 129, 130-1) (50 gp; 1 lb.) for the skill Heal.
- The held item ***Wednesday’s left eye*** (*Dragon* #324 29) (6,000 gp; 0 lbs.) grants the bearer, among other benefits, a +4 bonus to Heal skill checks.

I'm interested in official ways--specifically magical and mundane items but more obscure things like affiliations, contacts, magical locations, and teamwork benefits are cool--to get bonuses to Heal skill checks. *Dungeons and Dragons, 3rd Edition* items that weren't reprinted for *3.5*; items from *Dragon* and *Dungeon* magazines; and items from Wizards of the Coast's Web articles are all acceptable in addition to items from traditional sources.

I'm *not* looking for any of the many spells that can improve a creatures Wisdom score or improve skill checks. I'm also *not* looking for custom magic items (*Dungeon Master's Guide* 285), even if they use the *Arms and Equipment Guide*'s guidelines for Items That Grant Feats (128). I know that a generous DM can allow nigh-infinite Fine creatures to aid another (*PH* 65-6); I don't want those, either. Finally, I don't need a list of base or prestige classes that grant bonuses to Heal checks.

---

#### "Why?"

I'm writing a prestige class and considering allowing the class to make Heal skill checks to generate extraordinary effects mimicking spells. I want to know A) if there's a Heal-skill-check-breaking item that I missed, and B) if there's an interesting reward I can offer the character that will increase his bonus with Heal skill checks.

Answer (score 1):

With a cursory search, I found a couple items.  The reference I found indicated Heal Kits can come in +1 to +10, not just +2.  I also found: Magic Item Compendium - Healing Belt – Gain a +2 competence to Heal Checks and has 3 healing charges. There are also Psionic Shards that can be up to +10 to a skill ability that can be applied to Heal.

I noted that these also have instructions on what it takes to craft the items. The belt for example requires Craft Wonderous Item, Cure Moderate Wounds, 500GP, 40XP and 1 day to craft. How much would the benefits and cost scale up if Cure Critical Wounds was used instead?

Using templates from existing items or the rules for crafting you could generate any number of items that can benefit your player character.  You could also apply an item that grants a feat, or craft one and apply the feat Skill Master and specify Heal, this would provide a +10 to Heal Check.

Skill Mastery is also a feat the play could gain that grants a +10 to the skill.  If you are writing the Prestige class you could incorporate Skill Mastery Heal as a special gained at a given level.  You could possibly create an Improved Skill Mastery Heal that stacks for a second +10 if you want the PRC to have healing that powerful.

Hope you find this helpful.

Comment: Totally missed the *healing belt.* Good catch. Can you point me to your source of the kits that can provide bonuses of greater than +2?

Comment: http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Healing_Kit_(3.5e_Equipment) is a source for Healing kits as a quick reference.  Unfortunately other site references are blocked for me at work, but a google search will bring them up.

Comment: Mongoose Publishing: Knowledge (Anatomy) gives +2 synergy bonus to Heal checks. DM Could houserule that Profession (Doctor) could provide a +2 synergy bonus. Item Familiar from Unearthed Arcana could also give big bonuses to Heal skill.